# Lua atempt to call a nil method

Tags: lua

I'm having trouble understanding why this code results in an error.  Shouldnt the line t.__index = self make sure the table t looks up the init function in Vector?

```
Vector = {}
Vector.init = function(self,x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end
mt = {}
mt.__call = function(self,...)
    local t = {}
    t.__index = self
    setmetatable(t,self)
    t:init(...)
    return t
end
setmetatable(Vector,mt)
Vector.__add = function(self,other)
    return Vector(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)
end
local t = Vector(5,5)
local l = Vector(5,5)
local v = l + t
print(v.x,v.y)
```

Im also terrible with lua code. I usually use someone else's class library as i cant write my own.  Just seems confusing to me.

Ive revised my code as follows.

```
Vector = {}
Vector.__index = Vector
Vector.mt = {}
Vector.init = function(self,x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end
setmetatable(Vector,Vector.mt)
Vector.mt.__call = function(self,...)
    local t = {}
    setmetatable(t,self)
    t:init(...)
    return t
end
Vector.__add = function(self,other)
    return Vector(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)
end
local t = Vector(5,5)
local l = Vector(5,5)
local v = l + t
print(v.x,v.y)
```

Works as intended

I came up with this as a general class system

```
Class = {}
Class.mt = {}
setmetatable(Class,Class.mt)
Class.mt.__call = function(self,name)
    local class = {}
    class.name = name
    class.__index = class
    class.mt = {}
    class.mt.__call = function(self,...)
        local t = {}
        setmetatable(t,self)
        t.init(t,...)
        return t
    end
    setmetatable(class,class.mt)
    return class
end
Vector = Class("Vector")
Vector.init = function(self,x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end
Vector.__add = function(self,other)
    return Vector(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)
end
```

I have no idea how to do inheritence

I feel like giving up.  Im not good at this

I seemed to have achieved multiple inheritance via mixins.

Just need to declare the super functions before creating the sub classes or else it will not mixin the functions.

```
Class = {}
Class.mt = {}
setmetatable(Class,Class.mt)
Class.mt.__call = function(self,name,...)
    local class = {}
    class.name = name
    class.parents = {...}
    class.__index = class
    class.mt = {}
    for k,v in pairs(class.parents) do
        for i,j in pairs(v) do
            if 
                i ~= "init" and 
                i ~= "parents" and 
                i ~= "mt" and 
                i  ~= "__index" and 
                i ~= "name" then class[i] = j end
        end
    end
    class.mt.__call = function(self,...)
        local t = {}
        setmetatable(t,self)
        t.init(t,...)
        return t
    end
    setmetatable(class,class.mt)
    return class
end
Vector = Class("Vector")
Vector.init = function(self,x,y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
end
Vector.__add = function(self,other)
    return Vector(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)
end
Vector.update = function()
    print("update from vector")
end
Vector3 = Class("Vector3",Vector)
Vector3.init = function(self,x,y,z)
    print("hello")
    Vector.init(self,x,y)
    self.z = z
end
Vector3.__add = function(self,other)
    local v = Vector.__add(self,other)
    return Vector3(v.x,v.y,self.z+other.z)
end
a = Vector3(1,2,3)
a.update()
print(a.z)
```

Comment: I firgured it out.  The line is supposed to be self.__index = self.  Self in this context refers to Vector.

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it.